# Git: Finding the two nearest commits of two repositories?

Tags: git

I have a collection of repositories that were derived from one another. Instead of creating a new branch for each major revision, a new repo B was created with the last state of the old one A.

I'm trying to bring these poor things back together, but to do so I need to find out which commit in A was the initial commit of B taken from.

How can I do that?

Edit: note that there is no certainty that B's initial commit contains identical source to one of A's commits. For example, a Makefile or something may have been changed to accomodate the new name of the project.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I expect that the **source tree** of the initial commit in `B` is *completely* the same as in some commit(s) in `A`. In this case you can solve your problem relatively easily:

First look at the `tree` field of the first commit in `B`: `git log --pretty=raw <B_initial_commit>` and remember SHA-1 of the tree.

Now you can do `git log --pretty=raw` in the A repository and try to locate this SHA-1. If you find such a commit, then bingo! you've got the required (actually there could be a few of them, but it doesn't matter since all these commits have absolutely same source trees, just pick any).

The situation, however, could be slightly worse. Those who "cloned" that B repository could omit some of the files (e.g. `.gitignore` or other files, which don't make a source tree different for a human, but make it different for a robot).

**Edit**: here's the possible solution for the case. The idea is to understand what changes have been done to the *initial* commit of B when B was forked from A and make a script that would revert such changes. Or if the changes are too complex to be easily reverted, then simply remove such files from both B and A and then simply compare the resulted source trees again with the method described above.

So suppose you'd make such a script, which e.g. removes (some of) Makefiles and perform other possible changes on B, and another corresponding script for A. Then you use [git filter-branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) with **tree-filter** and thus create 2 new repositories from A and B, let's call them A' and B'. Then as described above, you may try locate a tree within A' with the same SHA1 as the SHA1 of the tree of the initial commit in B'. Since commits in A and A' correspond one by one, then you get then solution.

Comment: Right, the files in the initial commit of B varied slightly, for example by changing the project name in some Makefiles. So I'll have to compare the tree objects.

One thing that helps is I can limit my search to commits in A only up to the timestamp of B's initial commit, and a bit earlier (like a day or two).